# Close Button Not Showing in FancyApps

Tags: jquery, css, button, fancybox

Right now, the close button is only showing within the boundaries of the image itself. The path to the fancybox_sprite.png image is correct and in the jQuery, I have it set like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $(".fancybox").fancybox ({
            openEffect  : 'fade',
            closeEffect : 'fade',
            closeBtn: true
        });
    });
```

This is currently my testing station, which you can click [here](http://abrielshipley.com/new/); and this is the [FancyApps link itself](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) to show you the examples provided.

Any help is very much appreciated! =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `http://abrielshipley.com/new/css/style_vertical.css` CSS file you have `overflow: hidden` set on every element (`*`).

Either remove that, or set `overflow: visible` for the fancybox container `div` and it's children.

Comment: I am suffering the same issue but can't seem to fix it with setting overflow:visible seemingly on all fancybox box divs! The close button is trimmed in IE8. See my gallery at the bottom of this page. Can you help? http://dev.enterf1.com/british-grand-prix.php